# Reading value with I2C protocol from magnetoscope

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller

I'm pretty new still to all this. So please excuse me if there is something obvious.

I have been struggling with the included datasheet for a magnetoscope. For some reason it seems like everything is working, but when I wave a magnet at it, I'm not really getting any response in the serial.

So here is some information.

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(9600); // start serial communication at 9600bps
}

void loop() {
  int reading = 0;
  int Address = 30;
  Wire.beginTransmission(Address);
  Wire.write(byte(0x03));
  Wire.write(byte(0x04));
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(Address, 2);
  delay(10);
  if (2 <= Wire.available()) {
    reading = Wire.read();
    reading = reading << 8;
    reading |= Wire.read();
    Serial.println(int(reading));
  }

  delay(250); // wait a bit since people have to read the output :)
}
```

With this code, I receive a number.

```
-5637
-5637
-5637
-5637
-5637
```

But then if I remove the following line `Wire.write(byte(0x03));`, my output does not change. The value from the device is supposed to be expressed as two's complement.

So at first I thought I didn't know how to send multiple bytes to the device, but after some research I found that I was doing it right (I think).

Then if I only put `Wire.write(byte(0x03));` I receive "0" as response. Reading the datasheet I see that response 0 means that the command is invalid.

I included the datasheet to this post. Can someone point me in the right dirrection? The IC I'm using is an LSM303DLHC and I'm using it from this "[sheild](https://abra-electronics.com/sensors/sensors-magneto-en-2/sens-27-gy-511-lsm303dlhc-compass-3-axis-magnetometer-3-axis-accelerometer-module.html)".

Here is the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/56/ec/ac/de/28/21/4d/48/DM00027543.pdf/files/DM00027543.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00027543.pdf).

The following picture is a picture of the communication of the bus.

[image]

Comment: Please show a MCVE. Currently you have no headers included and have omitted the declaration of `reading` and your `setup()` function.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, Thanks for the response, your right, i was thinking of showing what i though the problem could be in, but your right im going to update this now.

Also could you tell me what MCVE mean ?

Comment: It's here... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That API takes the 7-bit address(30-0x1E). AFAICT from the scope the library is setting the r/w bit correctly. I think the problem is that OP is doing a write and a read when page 20 specifies that a write-read operation is needed. Try endTransmission(false). Also don't know why he is writing 0x04 into the 0x03 register.

Comment: Try looking at line 78 onwards here... https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/LSM303DLHC/blob/master/Arduino/LSM303DLHC.ino

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following code does this, which is like Table 11 in the datasheet:

```
  Wire.beginTransmission(Address);  // START and write to device address 0x1E
  Wire.write(byte(0x03));           // Set the register pointer to sub-address 0x03
  Wire.write(byte(0x04));           // Write a value of 0x04 to sub-address 0x3
  Wire.endTransmission();           // STOP.
```

Then I suspect the device's register pointer gets automatically incremented from register 0x03 to 0x04.  And then the rest of your code maybe reads two bytes from sub-address 0x04 and 0x05.

You didn't express your intention for your code but I suspect the above is NOT what you intended.  My guess is that you intend to *read* two bytes from device address 0x1E, sub-address 0x03 and sub-address 0x04.  Is that right?

You should be doing an operation like what is described in Table 13.

```
  Wire.beginTransmission(Address);  // START and write to device address 0x1E
  Wire.write(byte(0x03));           // Set the register pointer to sub-address 0x03
  Wire.requestFrom(Address, 2);     // REPEAT-START and read 2 bytes from sub-address 0x03 and 0x04
```